# Prevent repeating background from clipping

Tags: css

I have the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/umxvq52j/ of a repeat background of stars.

CSS:

```
.stars
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 320px;
    background: url('http://i59.tinypic.com/2i95zzk.png') left center repeat-x;
}
```

What I want to do is make it so that the stars perfectly fill the space and you don't get the edges of the stars cropped! So if I'm on a smaller screen it will show 2-3 stars flush, then 6-7 etc, and never show half a star.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want the space between a background repeat to expand so that it will fit the screen (stars will touch left and right edges of the screen) or keep the stars touching each others and display only whol stars (stars will only touch left edge of the screen)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for but take a look at the `round` attribute of background

```
background: url('http://i59.tinypic.com/2i95zzk.png') round 0 0;
```

Credit goes to [CSS3 background spacing](http://www.impressivewebs.com/space-round-css3-background/)

Comment: To be precise, `round` is a new value for the `background-repeat` property. Unfortunately, Firefox hasn't implemented any of the new values for `background-repeat` yet - see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=548372 Other browsers have, with Chrome being the most recent.

Answer (score 6):

For the best browser support and if you don't mind JavaScript and a bit more typing:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umxvq52j/4/)

HTML:

```
<div class="stars_con">
<div class="stars"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.stars_con
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 320px;

}
.stars{
    background: url('http://i59.tinypic.com/2i95zzk.png') left center repeat-x;
    width:100%;height: 320px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).on("resize load", function () {
    var screenWidth = $(window).width();
    var starWidth = 320;
    var width = screenWidth - (screenWidth % starWidth);
    $('.stars').css({
        'width': width
    });
});
```

Comment: This `screenWidth - (screenWidth % starWidth)` is owsome

Answer (score 1):

Use this to prevent background from clipping

```
background-repeat: space;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something pretty hacky and if you have set measurements on your images:
[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/VeldMuijz/j4ztrhgp/)

```
.stars
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 320px;
    background: url('http://placehold.it/200x200') left center repeat-x;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .stars
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 320px;
    background: url('http://placehold.it/200x200'),url('http://placehold.it/200x200'); 
    background-position: left, right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
}
}
```